# In VF page record in not updating from other pagination pages. In Vf used jquery pagination

Tags: visualforce, jquery, pagination

I've created the VF page to mass update the records. Records are displayed using page block table. I've used the [jquery pagination](https://datatables.net/).

When we submit data from page it should update to the system. Its working.

But problem is whenver we changes records from multiple pages and click update then records is not updating from other pages.

The record is updating only from page from which we click on update button. and not updating for other pages records.

What could be the workaround to resolve this. Please help on this.

VF page Code :

```
    <apex:page controller="addpatienttratementCntrl" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"/>
    <apex:includescript value=" //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

   <style>
    .ui-widget-overlay{
        background: black;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
        function adddataTable(){
            $('table.dataTable').dataTable({ 'destroy': true,}); 
            inijquery();
        }

         function inijquery(){
             $('tr').on('click',function(){ //alert('0');
                        //if($('#j_id0:j_id6:PSwithPat:j_id35:j_id37:52:j_id41').prop('checked'))alert('t'); else alert('f');
                $('.treatment').closest('tr').find('.colm-1').click(function() {
                   $(this).closest('tr').find('.colm-1').not(this).prop('checked', false);//alert('1');
                });

                $('.treatment').closest('tr').find('.colm-2').click(function() {
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('.colm-3').prop('checked', false);//alert('2');
                });

                $('.treatment').closest('tr').find('.colm-3').click(function() {
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('.colm-2').prop('checked', false);//alert('3');
                });
            });
          }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('table.dataTable').dataTable({});
            inijquery();


                 /**********/
                 $( "#PSupdate" ).dialog({
                    resizable: true,
                    height:150,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    open: function() {
                         var markup = 'Do you want to Complete your Report?<br/>Once you complete, you cannot update.';
                         $(this).html(markup);
                    },
                    title: "Confirmation",
                    buttons: {
                        "Yes": function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            updatePSConcludeJob();
                            //alert('Yes');
                        },
                        "No": function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            updatePS();
                        }
                    }
                });

                 /***********/

               });

        });

        function callSave(){
            var r = confirm("Are you sure want to save?");
            if(r == true) {     
                //alert('true');           
                createPSConcludeJob();
            }else{
                //alert('else');
               createPS();
            }
        }
    </script>

  <apex:form >


     <apex:actionFunction name="updatePSConcludeJob" action="{!updatePSConcludeJob}" reRender="PSwithPat" oncomplete="adddataTable();" status="status"/>
        <apex:actionFunction name="updatePS" action="{!updatePS}" reRender="PSwithPat" oncomplete="adddataTable();" status="status"/>

    <apex:pageBlock title="List of Patient Records with Patient Service" id="PSwithPat">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Patients" columns="1" collapsible="true">

             <apex:commandButton value="Update" onclick="$('#PSupdate').dialog('open'); return false;"/>

            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!WrapWithPatSerList}" var="a" title="PAtients" styleClass="dataTable">

                 <apex:column headerValue="Patient Name">
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!a.id}" target="_blank">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!a.Name}" />
                     </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Care Plan" styleClass="treatment">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.CarePlan}" styleClass="colm-2"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="TM" styleClass="treatment">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.TM}" styleClass="colm-1"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="TE" styleClass="treatment">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.TE}" styleClass="colm-1"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Refused" styleClass="treatment">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Refused}" styleClass="colm-1 colm-3"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Absent" styleClass="treatment">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Absent}" styleClass="colm-1 colm-3"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="III" styleClass="treatment">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.III}" styleClass="colm-1 colm-3"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Hospital" styleClass="treatment">
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Hospital}" styleClass="colm-1 colm-3"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageblocktable>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

 </apex:pageBlock>
 <div id="myModal"></div>
  <div id="PSupdate"></div>
 </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Apex Controller :

```
public with sharing class addpatienttratementCntrl {
string recordType = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sertype');
Id jobID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('jobid');
Id locationID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('locid');
Id region = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('reg');
Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Patient_Services__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(recordType).getRecordTypeId();

string retURL='/apex/addpatienttratement?jobid='+jobid+'&sertype='+recordType+'&locid='+locationID+'&reg='+region;
private list<Patient__C> Patist{get;set;}
public List<WrapWithoutPatSer> WrapWoutPatSerList{get;set;}
private list<Patient_Services__c> PatSerWithPat{get;set;}
public List<WrapWithoutPatSer> WrapWithPatSerList{get;set;}

public PageReference cancel() {
    PageReference nextPage = new PageReference('/' + jobID);
    return nextPage;
}

public PageReference updatePS() {
    updatePatientService();
    return null;
}

public addpatienttratementCntrl ()
{         
    WrapWoutPatSerList = new List<WrapWithoutPatSer>();
    WrapWithPatSerList = new List<WrapWithoutPatSer>();
    Patist= new List<Patient__C>();
    PatSerWithPat= new List<Patient_Services__c>();
    getPatientwithoutPS();
    getPatientwithPS();
}


public void getPatientwithPS()
{
  PatSerWithPat = [select id,Patient_full_name__c,Care_Plan__c,Treatment__c from Patient_Services__c where Patient__r.Location__c = :locationID and Job__c= :jobID ];
    if(WrapWithPatSerList.size() > 0) WrapWithPatSerList.clear();
    for(Patient_Services__c p : PatSerWithPat )
    {
        WrapWithoutPatSer w = new WrapWithoutPatSer();
        w.id= p.id;
        w.Name = p.Patient_full_name__c;
        if(p.Care_Plan__c == true)
            w.CarePlan =true; 
            if(p.Treatment__c == 'TM' )
                w.TM = true;
            if(p.Treatment__c == 'TE')
                w.TE = true;
            if(p.Treatment__c == 'Refused')
                w.Refused = true;
            if(p.Treatment__c == 'Absent')
                w.Absent = true;
            if(p.Treatment__c == 'III')
                w.III = true;
            if(p.Treatment__c == 'Hospital')
                w.Hospital = true;
       WrapWithPatSerList.add(w);
    }
}


Public void updatePatientService()
{
    List<Patient_Services__c> updatePatSer = new List<Patient_Services__c>(); 
    system.debug('@@@@size'+WrapWithPatSerList.size());

    for(WrapWithoutPatSer a : WrapWithPatSerList)
    {
        IF(a.CarePlan == true || a.TM== true || a.TE== true || a.Refused== true || a.Absent== true || a.III== true || a.Hospital == true)
        {   
            system.debug('@@@'+a.name);
            Patient_Services__c ps = New Patient_Services__c();
            ps.ID = a.id;

            if(a.CarePlan == true)
                ps.Care_Plan__c =true; 
            if(a.TM == true)
                ps.Treatment__c = 'TM';
            if(a.TE == true)
                ps.Treatment__c = 'TE';
            if(a.Refused == true)
                ps.Treatment__c = 'Refused';
            if(a.Absent == true)
                ps.Treatment__c = 'Absent';
            if(a.III == true)
                ps.Treatment__c = 'III';
            if(a.Hospital == true)
                ps.Treatment__c = 'Hospital';
         updatePatSer.add(ps);
        }
        else
            {
                Patient_Services__c ps = New Patient_Services__c();
                ps.ID = a.id;
                ps.Care_Plan__c =false;
                ps.Treatment__c = '';
                updatePatSer.add(ps);
            }
    }
    if(updatePatSer.size()>0)
        update updatePatSer;
} 

public PageReference updatePSConcludeJob() {
    updatePatientService();
    updateJob();
    PageReference nextPage = new PageReference('/' + jobID);
    return nextPage;
}

public void updateJob()
{
    sked__Job__c job = new sked__Job__c();
    Job.id=  jobID;
    job.Conclude_Patient__c=true;
    update job;
}

public class WrapWithoutPatSer
{
    public String ID{get;set;}
    public String Name{get;set;}
    public boolean CarePlan{get;set;}
    public boolean TM{get;set;}
    public boolean TE{get;set;}
    public boolean Refused{get;set;}
    public boolean Absent{get;set;}
    public boolean III{get;set;}
    public boolean Hospital{get;set;}

} 
}
```

Comment: You need to preserve the selection in local client side variable and on save you need to bind that variable with server.

Comment: @Amol Salesforce Stack Exchange isn't a place to find sample code. Please edit your question to focus on your specific problem to get assistance, and consider reading through [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).